# passing an object from login component to other via storage service

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass an object from one component to another. basically trying to pass token and other information as an object.
So when I login, I get some information in this format which I store in a const like this.

```
login() {
const token = {
  access_token: '832u3eui34334ui348348348u348u348u3483487348iu34yu7e3u32uie3u',
  userEmail: 'xyz@gmail.com'
};
 this.storageService.setToken(token);
}
```

//storage.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  setToken(token: object) {
    console.log(token);
     this.subject.next(token);
  }

  clearToken() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

   getToken(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    } 
}
```

And then in the other component constructor, I am trying to do this.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
 subscription: Subscription;
  someInfo;
this.subscription = this.storageService
      .getToken()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.someInfo = data;
         console.log(this.someInfo);
      });
```

But Currently it is giving me null.

Comment: you can make use of LocalStorage or a Session Storage.  Any specific reason you are trying to implement the above.

Comment: because I sometimes experienced that data stored in local storage get lost while refreshing so this is looking more reliable to me.